# gcc prints no such header file when compile it from upper level folder

Tags: c, gcc, makefile

I have this command here:

```
gcc -MD -fno-builtin -nostdinc -fno-stack-protector -Os -g -m32 -I. -c -o boot1lib.o
boot1lib.c
```

It runs fine if I run this in the folder where `boot1lib.o` and `boot1lib.c` located. But when I tried to run it from the upper folder i.e. `./boot/boot1/boot1lib.c`

It will shows:
`./boot/boot1/boot1lib.c:1:10: fatal error: boot1lib.h: No such file or directory #include <boot1lib.h>`

How do I modify the parameters to fix this issue? I am trying to build a makefile in the root folder so I don't have to copy and paste the command every time I tried to compile.

Comment: See the explanation in gcc's manual of the `-I` parameter, and change it accordingly. Do you understand how the `-I` parameter works?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I tried ```-Iboot/boot1``` and did not work either

Comment: Using `-Iboot/boot1` works for me using Clang, which is intended to be GCC compatible. If others cannot reproduce this with GCC, I suspect something was wrong in your attempt using `-Iboot/boot1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With GCC, `#include <file>` looks for files only in configured system directories, including those added with switches. `#include "file"` looks in the directory of the source file it is in.

Comment: So you are suggesting me should modify the header file instead the command?

Comment: @TravisSu: Unless `boot1lib.h` is intended to be installed in system directories, you should include it with `#include "boot1lib.h"` rather than `#include <boot1lib.h>`. That is the way GCC (and typically other compilers) is designed, and it is generally better to go with the design than against it.